# Add new rows to an existing dataframe/series

Tags: python, time-series, arima

My last 4 records of my dataset looks like this:

```
date    Outbound

11/26/2017 21:00    175.5846438
11/26/2017 22:00    181.1182961
11/26/2017 23:00    112.011672
11/27/2017 00:00    43.99501014
```

I have done my Out of Sample forecasting, and have predicted next 7 outputs i.e. for 27th November 01:00, 02:00 and so on..
My forecast is in form of a list like this: [100, 120, 130....]

How do i add the forecast along with the date to my dataframe or the series, as i need to plot the data..

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new DataFrame out of your additional list, and then merge it with the existing one. I think the easiest would be, if you had the data available as a list of dictionaries that also consists of the date index. I.e. something like (I'm assuming `df_original` is the data frame with your original values):

```
import datetime
import pandas

# Calculating your predictions (this should be replaced with an 
# appropriate algorithm that matches your case)

latest_entry = df_original.iloc[-1]
latest_datetime = latest_entry['date']

# We assume lastest_datetime is a Python datetime object.
# The loop below will create 10 predictions. This should be adjusted to make
# sense for your program. I'm assuming the function `compute_prediction()`
# will generate the predicted value. Again, this you probably want to tweak
# to make it work in your program :) 
# The computed predictions will be stored inside a list of dicts.

predictions = list()

for _ in range(10):
    predicted_date = latest_datetime + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
    predicted_value = compute_prediction()

    tmp_dict = {
        'date': predicted_date, 'Outbound': predicted_value
    }
    predictions.append(tmp_dict)

# Convert the list of dictionaries into a data frame.
df_predictions = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(predictions)

# Append the values of your new data frame to the original one.
df_concatenated = pandas.concat(df_original, df_predictions)
```

Of course, the `date` key used in `predictions` needs to be of the same type as the one used in your original data frame. The resulting `df_concatenated` would have both data frames together. To plot the outcome, you can just call `df_concatenated.plot()` (or call the appropriate plot function you need).

You can find more details on merging multiple data frames [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, but what if we are not aware of the last date value, for ex: the last date value is 11/27/2017 00:00, by looking at it, you prepared the dictionary which is fine, i don't want to have hard coded values, what if the last value would have been something else for ex: 11/27/2017 10:00, i hope you got my point..
How to take the last value and then increase by 1 hour...

Comment: Hi, I've tweaked the answer so it now fetches the latest entry and then goes from there ein 1 hour intervals to generate a prediction. Of course, the code above will need a little bit of tweaks to make it work in your context (e.g. the way you're computing predictions).

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers